# how to calculate number January month between two dates using php

Tags: php, date

I need to calculate how many January are their between two dates.
Example start date 2016-11-14 and end date 2018-01-01 so output would be 2.

Comment: what have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: `DateInterval`, `DateTime` are the keywords, try something and if you get stuck show what you've done, and you'll get certainly help here, but you won't get a solution out of the box without showing any effort...

Comment: i am not able to find any solution for this tried a lot

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner He doesn't want to know how many days there are between 2 dates.. He wants to count how many times the month january comes between 2 dates.